# Installable trigger notify without change in the event

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-calendar-api

We are working on Google Calendar Add-on and need some help regarding Add-on development. We are using the triggers to notify the us whenever there is any create/update/delete happen on the google calendar. So, there is any create/update/delete event that occurred into the user calendar then the trigger should notify our service with data but in our case, it is not working as expected due to which incident occurred. It is giving 1000's of notification without actually changing in the event.

We are using Triggers->`Installable Triggers` for the notification service.

Comment: I don't think this approach will work, I am using a scheduler based approach in which I am tracking all updated events. The calendar service is providing a flag for updated events and lastUpdatedTime. Based on which I am doing my changes.

Comment: What are the settings for your installable trigger? Can you give examples of notifications you are getting? What code is being run? What actually is your question?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]